# Как правильно вставить код картинки svg в html?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно изменять её цвет через css. Как правильно вставить? Видел несколько вариантов, один из них через path . Буду благодарен за объяснение или пример.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо вставить SVG непосредственно в HTML, то делаю через спрайты по данному мануалу: «[Как мы используем SVG-спрайты (новый способ)](http://glivera-team.github.io/svg/2016/06/13/svg-sprites-2.html)»<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001145412/http://glivera-team.github.io/svg/2016/06/13/svg-sprites-2.html)]</sup>. Можно менять цвет и размеры через CSS.

Если останутся вопросы — обращайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую применять следующий код вставки:

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="name.svg" width="320" height="240">
 <param name="src" value="name.svg">
</object>
```

Источник [инфо W3](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html)

Comment: А как управлять цветом заливки в таком случае?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет эта статья https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/ или эта http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-fill-color